# Oracle SQL: select on the left side of the where condition w/o using transaction

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause

I am new to SQL (Oracle) and I understand the basic. But there is one thing I want to know and didn't find any proper answer. Let's assume I have this given *table_1*:

```
 shipno   itemno   amount   weight_in_kg
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -
 001         1        1          50 
 001         6        6          60
 002         2        1          30
 002         6        3          30
 003         1        2         100
 004         5       10          25
```

Is it possible to create a query to show all shipnumbers where the total weight of a package will exceed 100 kg like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_1 
WHERE (
       SELECT sum(weight) 
       FROM table_1 
       WHERE shipno in (001, 002, 003, 004)
 ) >= 100
```

to get this output:

```
 shipno   itemno   amount   weight_in_kg
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -
 001       1         1        50 
 001       6         6        60
 003       1         2       100
```

Is there any solution which excludes transactions or scripts?
I know that I can definitely solve this with a transaction but I am just curious if it can be done without.

Thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: Have a sub-query that returns shipno's with sum => 100 kg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just what the `shipno` it's a simple aggregation. The HAVING clause acts as a filter like a WHERE clause but uses the aggregated value as its criterion.

```
select shipno 
       , sum(weight_in_kg) as total_weight_in_kg
from table1
group by shipno 
having sum(weight_in_kg) > 100
```

If you wanted all the details from the table you would use a variant of this query as a subquery:

```
select *
from table1
where shipno in (select shipno 
                 from table1
                 group by shipno 
                 having sum(weight_in_kg) > 100
    )
```

Comment: This is a very elegant way to solve it. I will try that immediately.

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from   your_table
where  shipno in (select shipno
                  from   your_table
                  group by shipno
                  having sum(weight) > 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a window function:

```
select shipno, itemno, amount, weight_in_kg
from (
  select shipno, itemno, amount, weight_in_kg, 
         sum(weight_in_kg) over (partition by shipno) as total_weight
  from the_table
) t
where total_weight > 100;
```

If you only need the shipno, then a `GROUP BY` query is the better and faster solution. But if you need all rows and columns for those shipments, this might be faster than a sub-select with an additional group by.